# Do we have In_category like function for tags?

Tags: tags

I have been using  "if (is_single() && in_category('keyword') )" to display custom links on the sidebar. I was wondering if we have in_tag or any similar function for tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L233) is the source of `in_category` function:

```
function in_category( $category, $post = null ) {
    if ( empty( $category ) )
        return false;

    return has_term( $category, 'category', $post );
}
```

You see, it's actually `has_term`. This is the same as [`has_category`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1150) function.

For tags, there's no `in_tag` function, but you can use [`has_tag`](http://look4wp.com/has_tag). It has the same functionality:

```
has_tag( $tag, $post );
```

Or you can use:

```
has_term( $tag, 'post_tag', $post );
```

where `$post` can be omitted (default is current post).

They're all the same!

Comment: I tried has_term before but it didn't work. However, has_tag works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. But I have a problem here. Is it possible to show custom links based on a generic tag? For example: I have tags like "iPhone News", "iPhone Apps" and I want to show custom links for "iPhone." I am using this code:

`<?php if (is_single() && has_tag('iphone') ) : ?>
 <ul><li><a href="http://...">Apple</a></li></ul><?php endif; ?>`

Replacing 'iphone' with 'iphone-news' shows custom links only on pages tagged with iPhone news. Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your custom link? BTW, if it doesn't related to this question, you should ask it separately.

Comment: These are links on the sidebar linking to "similar" pages, tags, categories, and so on. The function has_tag does it for me, but I was wondering if we can tweak it further.